# Asp.net Dropdownlist selected index changed AND TextChanged Events not Fire? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP>NET(C#). But I am using Winform before.

In my Project I have two dropdown list. if i change the one,.. the second will change auto.

But even event also not firing in ASP.net. Without event how to i manage that?.

```
<div id="Div1" class="ui-content ui-body-a" runat="server">
    <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlOutlet" runat="server" autopostback="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlOutlet_SelectedIndexChanged"
        ontextchanged="ddlOutlet_TextChanged">
                </asp:dropdownlist>
    <br />
    <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlServedAt" runat="server">
                </asp:dropdownlist>
    <br />
    <asp:button id="btnLogin" runat="server" text="LogIn" />
</div>
```

**C#**

I already Added items in both dropdown list in page load event. But When I change the ddlOutlet selected index changed Event not firing. So I tried to TextChanged Events Also. But nothing happened. What is problem?.

**Page Load Event -**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelpingFunctions hp = new HelpingFunctions();

    string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;username=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcubic;");
    string query = "SELECT c.Outlet_Master_Name,d.Fbserved_Served FROM mcs_user a, mcs_user_outlet b,outlet_master c,fb_served d WHERE a.Mcs_User_Id='" + id + "' and"
                    + " a.Mcs_User_Id = b.Mcs_User_Outlet_User_Id and c.Outlet_Master_Id = b.Mcs_User_Outlet_Outlet_Id and c.Outlet_Master_Id=d.Fbserved_outletid";           
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        ddlOutlet.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
        ddlServedAt.Items.Add(Reader[1].ToString());
    }
    connection.Close();


}
```

**Selected Item -**

```
protected void ddlOutlet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;username=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcubic;");
    string query = "select Fbserved_Served from fb_served where Fbserved_outletid = (select Outlet_Master_Id from outlet_master where Outlet_Master_Name ='" + ddlOutlet.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        ddlServedAt.SelectedItem.Value = Reader[0].ToString();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

I read some same issue problem solutions, but they told to set AutoPostBack="True". I checked that also.

I don't know why ASP.net hard to Event firing also?.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

In my Project,.. I am using jquerymobile(http://jquerymobile.com/) with ASP.Net and mysql.
I have two drop down list controls and ONE button.

But When I change the ddlOutlet selected index changed Event not firing. After the button Click the Events Are fired Correctly. But Before that They not fire. I do't know Why its happen.

I Give my Complete Code Below.

My Complete ASPX File :-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OutLet.aspx.cs" Inherits="MobileApp.OutLet" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.5; user-scalable=no;" />
     <link href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" data-ajax="false">
        <div id="mainheader" class="ui-header-fixed ui-bar-a">  

        </div>
        <div id="Div1" class="ui-content ui-body-a" runat="server">

           <%-- <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOutlet" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlOutlet_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    ontextchanged="ddlOutlet_TextChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlServedAt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="LogIn" 
                onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
               <%-- </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>   --%>       
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my Code -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MobileApp
{
    public partial class OutLet : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelpingFunctions hp = new HelpingFunctions();

            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;username=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcubic;");
                string query = "SELECT c.Outlet_Master_Name,d.Fbserved_Served FROM mcs_user a, mcs_user_outlet b,outlet_master c,fb_served d WHERE a.Mcs_User_Id='" + id + "' and"
                                + " a.Mcs_User_Id = b.Mcs_User_Outlet_User_Id and c.Outlet_Master_Id = b.Mcs_User_Outlet_Outlet_Id and c.Outlet_Master_Id=d.Fbserved_outletid";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    ddlOutlet.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
                    ddlServedAt.Items.Add(Reader[1].ToString());
                }
                connection.Close();
            }

        }

        protected void ddlOutlet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;username=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcubic;");
            string query = "select Fbserved_Served from fb_served where Fbserved_outletid = (select Outlet_Master_Id from outlet_master where Outlet_Master_Name ='" + ddlOutlet.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                ddlServedAt.SelectedValue = Reader[0].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        protected void ddlOutlet_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;username=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcubic;");
            //string query = "select Fbserved_Served from fb_served where Fbserved_outletid = (select Outlet_Master_Id from outlet_master where Outlet_Master_Name ='" + ddlOutlet.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";
            //MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //connection.Open();
            //MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //while (Reader.Read())
            //{
            //    ddlServedAt.SelectedItem.Value = Reader[0].ToString();
            //}
            //connection.Close();
        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I do not think the code where the ddlOutlet editor is filled with items.  Are you doing this in the Page_Load event?  If so, post this code as well

Comment: I added the my page load event coding Also. Please Give a solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Check for postback on page load on binding Dropdownlist, Like:  private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Bind First DropdownList Here
            }
        }

Comment: Are you by any chance using jquerymobile?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code as such. though you dont need to bind on every page load. Bind your dropdown list under if(!IsPostBack){ // put your code } . also, why do you need onTextChanged event here?

Comment: @PraveenLearnsEveryday I don't need onTextChanged. I checked if selected index changed is only not fired or other event also.

Comment: @rikitikitik I am using jquery mobile.

Comment: @Sagotharan Try adding data-ajax = "false" to the form tag of the page and see if it helps. Postbacks don't do well with jquery mobile's AJAX calls unfortunately.

Comment: @PankajTiwari AND PraveenLearnsEveryday I add the postback code also. But now also,.. event not firing. Is till any modification is bending?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try by Adding `Page.IsPostBack` in your `page_Load` event...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //your page load code.....
    }
}
```

**EDIT - 1**

**Sample Code of ASPX page in Web Application**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:DropDownList  id="id1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            onselectedindexchanged="id1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList  id="id2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Sample code of code behind in Web Application**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void id1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Sample code of ASPX page in Website**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList  id="id1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            onselectedindexchanged="id1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList  id="id2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Sample code of Code behind in Website**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void id1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried if (!IsPostBack) condition check before. Is need to check if (!Page.IsPostBack) Also?

Comment: can you update your complete aspx page and complete .cs page in your question?

Comment: now only i find,.. Event is fired after i click the button in my page. Why its happen?. Is any solution that even fire before the button has clicked?

Comment: I Updated Sir. Please See the Question.

Comment: Please check my edit. It is working fine in my sample in case of website as well as in web application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7734/discussion-between-sagotharan-and-pankaj-garg)

Answer (score 3):

Create the drop down list(the one that changes the content of the other one)

```
Activity: <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbActivity" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbActivity_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Then in your C#, your load event should be like this

```
if (Session["staffId"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
             cmbActivity.DataSource = a;
             cmbActivity.DataTextField = "activityName";
             cmbActivity.DataValueField = "activiyId";
            }
        }
```

Your selectedIndex_Changed method still remains the same. This should work. Have more than one item in the list to be sure.
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

OP already had this in his question, but I was missing `autopostback="True"`